# how do I make an array of new objects that implement a common interface in java

Tags: java, arrays

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
interface a{} 
class b implements a{
    a[] array; 
    new b(){
        array={ new aImplementer(), new aImplementer(), new aImplementer()}; 
    } 
}
```

Why can't I do this? Am I just doing it wrong? Right now the error I'm getting is an illegal start of expression error at the { part of array={

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your syntax is off. I believe you want something like this  (Final revision--actually tested this time--then redone after my changes were overridden.)

```
interface A{} 

class AImplementer implements A{};

class B { 
    A[] array; 
    B(){  
        array=new A[]{ new AImplementer(), new AImplementer(), new AImplementer()}; 
    } 
 }
```

There, guaranteed to compile or twice your money back :)

Also threw in "classes should start with an upper case letter" for no charge.

Comment: this gives me an <identifier> expected error right after the new

Comment: is it because you didn't define aImplementor?  There, I think I put what you were trying for.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Also note that if you really intended to use b as "aImplementer" then your logic is also wrong because b will recurse in the constructor and create b's until you run out of memory.

Comment: b is not an aImplementor, it is a collection of aImplementors

Comment: In that case, b should not implement a, and my answer above is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can only assign an array to an array literal (I'm not sure what you call these beasts) at declaration of the variable.  So this may be OK

```
// array literal assigned at variable declaration
a[] array = { new aImplementer(), new aImplementer(), new aImplementer()};  
new b(){

}
```

But what you have where you declare it first and then assign it at a different spot isn't OK.  Why? I'm not sure other than that's how it is in the JLS.

Edit: Updated compiled/tested code:

```
interface A {
}

class AImplementer implements A {
};

class B {
   A[] array = {new AImplementer(), new AImplementer(), new AImplementer()};

   B() {

   }
}
```

Comment: I think you still need the second "new" as in: a[] array = new a[]{blah} (but it wasn't me who downvoted you--that was some fly-by).

Comment: @Bill: no, the code compiles fine without the new.  Try it yourself to be sure.  You need the new a[] only if initiating the array when not at declaration.  Either of our code will work.  +1 for your great example.  /Pete

Comment: @Bill K +1 for nicer code. BTW: Those codes both compile fine `String[] str1={"", "", ""};
    String[] str2=new String[]{"", "", ""};` @Hovercraft Full Of Eels +1 for being first giving 'the same' answer and being down-voted, why hell knows?

Comment: @Boro: thanks, but down votes don't really bug me as I've got as many points as I need. You can't really redeem them for nuthin'  :)

Comment: You're right--didn't ever notice that differentiation, good to know.  +1

Comment: (I agree about the points--but I really hate flyby downvotes--It should require a comment whenever you down-vote and I didn't like the way it looked like I had).